# Pandas: drop rows in which a certain substring is not present

Tags: python, pandas

So I have  this currently I am very new to this stuff

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'Should_work2222.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file_name)[['Assignees_y', 'Serials']]

result = pd.DataFrame(df)

print(result)
```

This code worked for me I got exactly what I wanted but I am trying to only receive certain words like Fastenal with the serial number I know I can use excel to only get the information I want but I wanna try to use python

```
                        Assignees_y     Serials
0      Fastenal-OB(any)-locker 110  376txk1233
1             Fastenal - locker 70  376TXK1235
2              Fastenal-locker 105  376txk1244
3           Fastenal - OB Dock 111  376txk6431
4                              bin  376txr4241
5                          Missing  376txr5214
6                             lost  376txk5352
7                             lost  376txk1324
8                             lost  376TXR6446
9              available in master  376TXK5335
10                      IB Receive  376txk1424
11                      IB Receive  376txk1601
12                      IB Receive  376TYR5366
13                      IB Receive  376TXR5535
14     Fastenal - IB Rcv locker 91  376txk6434
15      Fastenal - IB Rcvlocker 93  376txr5553
16     Fastenal - IB Rcv locker 94  376TXR5333
17  Fastenal - IB Stw - locker 102  376TXK3532
18  Fastenal - IB Stw - locker 103  376txk5353
19                          IB Rcv  376txk5322
20                            lost  376txk2625
21                              OB  376txk2434
22        Fastenal-pick- locker 82  376txk6454
23         Fastenal-pack-locker 84  376txk5343
24         Fastenal-pack-locker 90  376TXK1244
```

I wanna get rid of this and only get Fastenal and their serials

Comment: What you want and your issue are absolutely unclear. Please explain more clearly.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining correctly I basically just want certain Assignees like Fastenal and its serial number instead of everything else in my excel file. Was that a better explanation if not I apologize

Comment: What is "Fastenal"? this word doesn't even appear in your example.

Comment: Okay now I have fixed it So I am only trying to get the Fastenal-pick lockers instead of all that extra stuff can I use df.drop??

Comment: `df[df["Assignees_y"].str.contains("Fastenal")]`

Comment: Please update your post title to actually reflect the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.contain` method:

```
df.loc[df.Assignees_y.str.contains('Fastenal')]

                       Assignees_y     Serials
0      Fastenal-OB(any)-locker 110  376txk1233
1             Fastenal - locker 70  376TXK1235
2              Fastenal-locker 105  376txk1244
3           Fastenal - OB Dock 111  376txk6431
14     Fastenal - IB Rcv locker 91  376txk6434
15      Fastenal - IB Rcvlocker 93  376txr5553
16     Fastenal - IB Rcv locker 94  376TXR5333
17  Fastenal - IB Stw - locker 102  376TXK3532
18  Fastenal - IB Stw - locker 103  376txk5353
22        Fastenal-pick- locker 82  376txk6454
23         Fastenal-pack-locker 84  376txk5343
24         Fastenal-pack-locker 90  376TXK1244
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop all rows that don't contain the text "Fastenal":

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

stream = StringIO("""
Assignees_y,Serials
Fastenal-OB(any)-locker 110,376txk1233
Fastenal - locker 70,376TXK1235
Fastenal-locker 105,376txk1244
Fastenal - OB Dock 111,376txk6431
bin,376txr4241
Missing,376txr5214
lost,376txk5352
lost,376txk1324
lost,376TXR6446
available in master,376TXK5335
IB Receive,376txk1424
IB Receive,376txk1601
IB Receive,376TYR5366
IB Receive,376TXR5535
Fastenal - IB Rcv locker 91,376txk6434
Fastenal - IB Rcvlocker 93,376txr5553
Fastenal - IB Rcv locker 94,376TXR5333
Fastenal - IB Stw - locker 102,376TXK3532
Fastenal - IB Stw - locker 103,376txk5353
IB Rcv,376txk5322
lost,376txk2625
OB,376txk2434
Fastenal-pick- locker 82,376txk6454
Fastenal-pack-locker 84,376txk5343
Fastenal-pack-locker 90,376TXK1244
""")
df = pd.read_csv(stream)

mask = df["Assignees_y"].str.contains("Fastenal")
df = df.loc[mask]

print(df)
```

which prints:

```
                       Assignees_y     Serials
0      Fastenal-OB(any)-locker 110  376txk1233
1             Fastenal - locker 70  376TXK1235
2              Fastenal-locker 105  376txk1244
3           Fastenal - OB Dock 111  376txk6431
14     Fastenal - IB Rcv locker 91  376txk6434
15      Fastenal - IB Rcvlocker 93  376txr5553
16     Fastenal - IB Rcv locker 94  376TXR5333
17  Fastenal - IB Stw - locker 102  376TXK3532
18  Fastenal - IB Stw - locker 103  376txk5353
22        Fastenal-pick- locker 82  376txk6454
23         Fastenal-pack-locker 84  376txk5343
24         Fastenal-pack-locker 90  376TXK1244
```